# Gradle - Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLoggerRepository()Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerRepository

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar, log4j

I have a project in the Eclipse IDE that using the gradle plugin and its working and running successfully within the IDE, However, when I export the project into a jar file using eclipse and run it via cmd, java -jar test1.jar, I get this reoccurring error:

"Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLoggerRepository()Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerRepository;"

From my understanding the log4j-1.2.17.jar file is being retrieved by gradle and is packaged when exported to a runnable jar, using eclipse, but I still get this error.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
         dirs 'F:/flatRepo'
     }     
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    runtime('org.hsqldb:hsqldb')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    //
//   Dimensions dependencies

    // log4j
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.4'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject
compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'


}

task setHttpProxyFromEnv {
    def map = ['HTTP_PROXY': 'http', 'HTTPS_PROXY': 'https']
    for (e in System.getenv()) {
        def key = e.key.toUpperCase()
        if (key in map) {
            def base = map[key]
            def url = e.value.toURL()
            println " - systemProp.${base}.proxy=${url.host}:${url.port}"
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyHost", url.host.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPort", url.port.toString())
        }
    }
}

build.dependsOn setHttpProxyFromEnv
```

Comment: Run with -cp option.

Comment: Extract jar and check in extracted files. Extract using zip